# AngularJS Ajaxify entire website

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I' currently working with History API and jQuery in order to ajaxify my website.

All links fires ajax calls to retrieve the page and to replace actual content with fetched content, so the user can navigate without page reload. How can I achieve this using only AngularJS ?

I took a look at `$location` doc, and I successfully created a directive on links. This directive stop the default event and use `$location.path()` to set the new url.

```
angular.module('directives.AjaxNavigation', [])

.directive('a', ['$location', function($location) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            iElement.bind('click', function(e) {
                console.log(iElement.attr('href'));
                scope.$apply($location.path(iElement.attr('href')));
                e.preventDefault();
            });

        }
    }
}]);
```

How can I now capture the "urlChange" event in order to make an ajax call each time it is fired ?

Comment: I think you need to look at [`$routeProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)

Comment: That is what the `$location` service already do. See [$location guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location), and you might need the HTML5 mode.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Comment: @akn But the thing is I don't want to use the route module of angular. I want to use the html generated by my server, not in a template. I would like to manually make an http request to the link href, and replace my body width the html body fetched.

Comment: @runTarm I was looking at this page. But I really don't get when they capture the urlChange event? I'm guessing it is in the fake-browser.js part, but I don't understand why they use this decorator on $browser, also there is no doc on $browser ("because it is an private API not designed for famework users")

Comment: Also see [$location documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location), there are `$locationChangeStart` and `$locationChangeSuccess` events, they might be helpful.